# Perl: Find a sum of an array recursively with tail call optimization

Tags: recursion, tail-recursion, perl

I'm trying to make a tail optimized recursive function.

```perl
sub sum {
    my ($first, @rest) = @_;

    return @rest
        ? $first + sum(@rest)
        : $first;
}

say sum(1 .. 100);
```

It works for 100 elements however, it fails for 100_000 elements with `Out of memory` message.

How can improve the code to make the recursion working with more elements?

**Edit**

Tail call optimized version of the above function:

```perl
use feature qw( current_sub );

sub sum_tco {
    my $loop = sub {
        my ($sum, $first, @rest) = @_;
        $sum += $first;

        return @rest
            ? __SUB__->($sum, @rest)
            : $sum;
    };

    return $loop->(@_);
}
```

It appears that Perl 5 doesn't support TCO.

**How to make TCO in Perl (if possible)?**

Comment: That's not a tail-recursive function, And IIRC perl doesn't do tail call optimization anyways without some funky `goto` usage.

Comment: You could use `reduce` from `List::Util`, which does a left fold. Or do it in a loop. And a different language for playing with TCO and deep recursion (I'm partial to scheme). It's just not something perl is really well suited for. But [here's an example](https://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=161611) of `goto` based tail calls in perl.

Comment: I know `reduce` and `sum` from `List::Util` and loops. My question is how to make TCO in Perl if possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a TCO version using that `goto` feature I mentioned in a comment:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use warnings;
use strict;
use feature qw/say/;

sub sum {
    return undef if @_ == 0;
    return $_[0] if @_ == 1;
    splice @_, 0, 2, $_[0] + $_[1];
    goto &sum;
}

say sum(1..100);
say sum(1..100_000);
```

From [the documentation](https://perldoc.pl/perlfunc#goto-LABEL):

> The goto &NAME form is quite different from the other forms of goto. In fact, it isn't a goto in the normal sense at all, and doesn't have the stigma associated with other gotos. Instead, it exits the current subroutine (losing any changes set by local) and immediately calls in its place the named subroutine using the current value of @_

I don't recommend actually *using* this as it's really, really slow compared to anything else, but it can be done.

Comment: Note that `goto &sum` isn't needed in the that example. Simply `&sum` would do. You'll create stack frames, but no new @_ is created, so you save lot of memory without sacrificing as much speed. In fact, if you're going to use `goto`, why not use `goto START;` (after placing `START:` before the first statement)? It would do exactly the same thing, but it would be soooo much cheaper! The approach you suggest is horrible.

Comment: In short, `goto &sub` is useful in fooling `caller`, but useless in TCO. Use `goto START` aka `while (1)`.

Comment: @ikegami `goto START` isn't TCO though, not actually having a call.

If you just do `return &sum;` instead of `goto &sum` you have  to add a `no warnings 'recursion';`.  So I would have recommended the goto form - except that I'm seeing it take much much longer, which I hadn't expected.

Comment: Huh? Optimizing the call away is still optimizing it.

Comment: I would use [this](https://tio.run/##XY3RCoIwGIXv9xTnogsl0S3oagi9R4gs@62BDd0cIuGzL5dB0dX/n@98cHqy3TEE7wiTskabm5MsJjda3Yzb35IavSUMU@HUXEjGnL/A@QeeDJjuuiMkIn0nwNIqG3hzpRa6xalGWYLL33JXn3n1LcVWur7TDa0sA89wyD7aPl5RRWdhyzqu5jieiDwXnKfyD9Q8whBe "Perl 5 – Try It Online") regardless if it's TCO or not.

Answer (score 4):

You are correct that Perl doesn't perform tail call optimization.

If you had a tail call, you could optimize it yourself. But that said, you don't have a tail call. The recursive call is followed by an addition.

So let's start by changing the sub to have only tail calls. This is done by passing forward the information needed to perform that last operation.

```
sub _sum {
   my ($acc, $first, @rest) = @_;
   $acc += $first;
   return @rest ? _sum( $acc, @rest ) : $acc;
}

sub sum {
   my (@rest) = @_;
   return undef if !@rest;
   return _sum( 0, @rest );
}
```

Now we can perform tail call optimizations.

1. Place the body of the recursive subroutine in an infinite loop.
2. Replace `recurse(...)` with `do { @_ = ...; next; }`.

First in the helper.

```
sub _sum {
   while (1) {
      my ($acc, $first, @rest) = @_;
      $acc += $first;
      if (@rest) {
         @_ = ( $acc, @rest );
      } else {
         return $acc;
      }
   }
}

sub sum {
   my (@rest) = @_;
   return undef if !@rest;
   return _sum( 0, @rest );
}
```

Then in the main sub.

```
sub sum {
   my (@rest) = @_;
   return undef if !@rest;

   @_ = ( 0, @rest );
   while (1) {
      my ($acc, $first, @rest) = @_;
      $acc += $first;
      if (@rest) {
         @_ = ( $acc, @rest );
      } else {
         return $acc;
      }
   }
}
```

Done.

...kinda. There are so many other cleanups and optimizations we can do now.

Let's start by improving the flow.

```
sub sum {
   my (@rest) = @_;
   return undef if !@rest;

   @_ = ( 0, @rest );
   while (1) {
      my ($acc, $first, @rest) = @_;
      $acc += $first;
      return $acc if !@rest;

      @_ = ( $acc, @rest );
   }
}
```

No need to create a new `$acc` every pass through the loop.

```
sub sum {
   my (@rest) = @_;
   return undef if !@rest;

   my $acc = 0;
   while (1) {
      my ($first, @rest) = @_;
      $acc += $first;
      return $acc if !@rest;

      @_ = @rest;
   }
}
```

There's no need to use `@_` anymore.

```
sub sum {
   my (@rest) = @_;
   return undef if !@rest;

   my $acc = 0;
   while (1) {
      (my $first, @rest) = @rest;
      $acc += $first;
      return $acc if !@rest;
   }
}
```

Let's replace the expensive list assignment.

```
sub sum {
   my (@rest) = @_;
   return undef if !@rest;

   my $acc = 0;
   while (1) {
      my $first = shift(@rest);
      $acc += $first;
      return $acc if !@rest;
   }
}
```

Let's simplify the loop.

```
sub sum {
   my (@rest) = @_;
   return undef if !@rest;

   my $acc = 0;
   while (@rest) {
      my $first = shift(@rest);
      $acc += $first;
   }

   return $acc;
}
```

Let's replace the `while` loop with a cheaper foreach loop.

```
sub sum {
   my (@rest) = @_;
   return undef if !@rest;

   my $acc = 0;
   for my $first (@rest) {
      $acc += $first;
   }

   return $acc;
}
```

`$first` and `@rest` are no longer appropriate variable names. We'll get rid of a useless copy of `@_` in the process.

```
sub sum {
   return undef if !@_;

   my $acc = 0;
   $acc += $_ for @_;
   return $acc;
}
```

If we initialize `$acc` to `undef`, the initial check is no longer needed.

```
sub sum {
   my $acc;
   $acc += $_ for @_;
   return $acc;
}
```

Tada!

Answer (score 3):

Here's a technique using a generic `run`-`recur` interface. This is effectively a [trampoline](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trampoline_(computing)) -

```
sub recur (*@values) {
  :{ 'recur' => &recur, 'values' => @values }
}

sub run (&f) {
  my $r = &f();
  while $r.isa(Hash) && $r{'recur'} === &recur {
    $r = &f(|$r{'values'});
  }
  return $r;
}
```

To use it, we pass a subroutine to `run` with loop arguments and their initial values -

```
sub sum ($n = 0) {
  run (sub ($m = $n, $r = 0) {
    if $m == 0 {
      return $r;
    }
    else {
      recur($m - 1, $r + $m);
    }
  })
}
```

NB we use `recur` with the updated arguments, instead of calling `sum` directly. Here's the output -

```
say sum(100_000);
# 100_000 + 99_999 + 99_997 + ... + 3 + 2 + 1 =
# => 5000050000

# cpu time: 10.61 sec
```

Here it is working on a range instead. We use loop variables to keep track of the range index, `$i` and the return value, `$r` -

```
sub sum (@range) {
  run (sub ($i = 0, $r = 0) {
    if $i >= @range {
      return $r;
    }
    else {
      recur($i + 1, $r + @range[$i]);
    }
  })
}

say sum(5..10);
# 5 + 6 + 7 + 8 + 9 + 10 =
# => 45

say sum(0..0);
# => 0

say sum(1..100_000);
# => 5000050000

# cpu time: 14.37 sec
```

The other techniques presented here ask that you dramatically change your program in order to avoid stack overflow. The unique `run`-`recur` interface allows you to think about your problem recursively *and* allow it to run in constant space.

---

Here is a revision compatible with Perl 5. To my surprise, this program is almost 50 times faster. Maybe the slow down is owed to the poor implementation of newer syntax sugars? It's anyone's guess...

```
use strict;
use warnings;

sub recur {
  { recur => \&recur, values => \@_ }
}

sub run {
  my ($f, @init) = @_;
  my $r = &{$f}(@init);
  while (ref $r eq ref {} && $r->{'recur'} == \&recur) {
    $r = &{$f}(@{$r->{'values'}});
  }
  return $r;
}

sub sum {
  my ($n) = @_;
  run (sub {
    my ($m, $r) = @_;
    if ($m == 0) {
      return $r;
    }
    else {
      recur($m - 1, $r + $m);
    }
  }, $n, 0);
}

print sum(100_000);
# => 5000050000

# cpu: 0.25 sec
# mem: 3 Mb
```

And the `sum` variant that takes a range input -

```
sub sum {
  my (@range) = @_;
  run (sub {
    my ($i, $r) = @_;
    if ($i >= @range) {
      return $r;
    }
    else {
      recur($i + 1, $r + $range[$i]);
    }
  }, 0, 0);
}

print sum(1..100_000);
# => 5000050000

# cpu: 0.27 sec
# mem: 12 Mb
```

Comment: Nice, but the question was about Perl 5 (not Perl 6) ?

Comment: @HåkonHægland, honestly I don't know perl at all. I learned just enough to answer this question. I was sad to see other answers suggesting the OP changes the entire "shape" of the original program just to make it stack-safe.

Comment: @HåkonHægland I found a [Perl 5 interpreter](https://tio.run/#perl5) and did my best. I updated my answer with a working Perl 5 implementation. It's mostly the same as Perl 6 but lacking the subroutine parameter sugar. Would you please let me know if you see any areas for improvement?

Comment: I was unable to get mem usage statistic in Perl 6. Any ideas on how to do that? I got mem usage for the Perl 5 programs using [this online compiler](https://rextester.com/l/perl_online_compiler).

Answer (score 0):

A file calls itself with a reducing number of arguments, inspired by this post: [A simple perl recursion example](http://blogs.perl.org/users/flymike/2013/12/a-simple-perl-recursion-example.html).

This, of course, is far away from a practical solution.

```perl
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature qw(say);

# Init the args at the first call
if (!@ARGV) {exec join(' ', $^X, $0, 1 .. 100_000)}

# Show progress
if (@ARGV % 100 == 0) {say scalar @ARGV}

my ($sum, $first, @rest) = @ARGV;
$sum += $first;

@rest
    ? exec join(' ', $^X, $0, $sum, @rest)
    : say $sum;
```